# JavaScript functions confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am in the process of learning AngularJS, and have the following code (from video tutorials I'm going through).

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
                    function EventController($scope, eventData) {
                        eventData.getEvent(function(event) {
                            $scope.event = event;
                        });
```

I am confused about this bit of the JavaScript `eventData.getEvent(function(event) { }` I admit that my JavaScript knowledge isn't super, but JavaScript functions are so strange in this regard compared to C# or Java functions/methods.

I understand that `eventData` is my AngularJS service and on that, I have a method called `getEvent()` but that does not take in an event object as a parameter! Here is my AngularJS service code:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        getEvent: function(successcb) {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data/event/1.json' }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                successcb(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Even when I tell myself "ignore object types and classes (thinking along C# / Java lines) and think of it as a plain object", then still I don't get where the **event parameter** in `eventData.getEvent(function(event) { }` came from!

Can someone please clarify?

Thanks

Comment: It's a param to an anonymous function. See [This wikibooks post](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_Functions) for more information

Comment: The parameter is just a parameter, it can be anything. But, in your case, that parameter is a *callback* - Callbacks are needed in JavaScript to continue processing work from ASYNC requests, as you have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually passing `event` as the parameter, you're passing that entire function as the parameter as a `callback`.  When `getEvent` reaches `.success`, it's calling that function (called `successcb` in the service), and passing `data` (where `data` is actually the `event` parameter that you're seeing in your controller.

It actually looks more like this:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        getEvent: function() {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data/event/1.json' }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               // successcb(data);
               // this is essentially what's happening, except in your controller...
               // ...so, this won't actually work because you don't have $scope in this service
               // but it's the same idea
               successcb(data);
               var successcb = function(event) {
                   $scope.event = event;
               };
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions can be treated as inline objects and can be passed as parameters.

for example you can have something like the below (pseodo code):

```
var x = function fun(){alert ('hi');};
callerFunction(x);
```

which is same as

```
callerFunction(function fun(){alert ('hi');});
```

Above is what is the concept behind and all modern JS libraries (like jQuery) leverage it to include all callback functions as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your service method is waiting for variable `REFERENCE_TO_FUNCTION`.
Maybe this example will make it more clear:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($http, $log) {
    return {
        getEvent: function(REFERENCE_TO_FUNCTION) {
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'data/event/1.json' }).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                REFERENCE_TO_FUNCTION(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }
    }
});
```